# Server error! Error 500 when using .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

I use this `.htaccess` file and when I access `http://localhost/sites/MVC/help` it does not return to `index.php` but gives:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: Your issue is that the rewrite_module is probably not loaded. You should check your Apache error logs to see the exact cause of your issue. Enclose it in inside of these tags: `<IfModule rewrite_module>/* You rewrite rules go here*/</IfModule>` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Comment: Usually caused by AllowOverride set to None instead of All

Comment: @LuckyBurger actually it's more likely that rewrite module is not enabled. If AllowOverride is set to `none` it will just simply ignore the htaccess file and it's not read.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your rewrite module. That will solve your error.